# How to create a running clock using date-fns

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, momentjs, date-fns

I am using date-fns for showing date and time.
I can able to dispay date and time using

`format(new Date(), "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss")` - `13-06-1994 21:34:50`

I want seconds to be running always. I tried so many methods but no able to render as expected.

Tried Code:

```
useEffect(() => {
const displayClock = setTimeout(
  new Date().toLocaleTimeString("en-US", {
    hour12: false,
  }),
  1000
);
setRunningClock(displayClock);
});
```

I see output as `number` type with numbers `1018, 1022`

Expected Output: `13-06-1994 21:34:50` seconds to be changed for every second. Expecting as string format

Comment: if we pass [] that will be called only once right I want to display for every second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First - it should be `setInterval`, not `setTimeout`.

Next - `displayClock` you currently have holds the ID that `setTimeout` returned. Those functions return the cancellation ids, so you got them, not the value of the function you expect. The callbacks passed to the `setTimeout` or `setInterval` do not return anything in that way.

Next - callback function passed to setTimeout (or setInterval in needed case) is invalid. What you passed evaluates immediately. You need to pass an actual callback function. `() => {...}`

Also, add a `[]` as a second parameter to `useEffect`. Without it, the hook will be executed on each render. And each render may not happen each 1 second as you expecting it.

And dont forget to call `clearInterval` as a cleanup function of the `useEffect` hook.

```js
const { useEffect, useState } = React;

// Moved function out just to set initial text value in state.
function getDisplayTime() {
  return new Date().toLocaleTimeString("en-US", {
    hour12: false
  });
}

function App() {
  const [clockText, setClockText] = useState(getDisplayTime());

  useEffect(() => {
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      setClockText(getDisplayTime());
    }, 1000);
    // If useEffect hook return a function - it will be called
    // when something in depsArray changed or when unmounting
    return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
  }, []);

  return <div className="App">{clockText}</div>;
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root")
).render(
    <App />
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Good answer, but `setInterval` of 1000 will drift over time, skipping some ticks eventually. I'd use a tighter loop than that.

Comment: how we can as tighter loop without setInterval

Comment: @SivaSai The interval callback should be executed "more often", 1000 ms (1 second) is usually 998 (less than a second) or 1002 (more than a second), +- like that. The idea is sometimes you will see the same date with same `seconds` values for 2 ticks. You can change 1000 to 500, for example, or to 250 or 333. Callback function will be executed more often and less chances to see incorrect time. @ggorlen please, correct me if im wrong.